# -match several $vars in if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, match

I have this, which doesn't work:

```
$var1 = "6.0.6001"
$var2 = "6.1.7001"
$var3 = "6.2.8074"
$var4 = "6.3.8074"
if($var1 -match "6.1.?" -or "6.2.?" -or "6.3.?") {
    write-host "1"
}else{
    write-host "2"
}
```

No matter what, 1 is returned.

What should this really look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code:

```
if("6.2.?" -or "6.3.?") {
    write-host "1"
}else{
    write-host "2"
}
```

It'll also return 1 no matter what.

Change your condition to:

```
if($var1 -match "6.1.?" -or $var1 -match "6.2.?" -or $var1 -match "6.3.?")
```

Or even better:

```
if($var1 -match "6.[1-3].?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on Adam 's answer. You `If` statement was not working as intended since PowerShell only saw three conditions you didnt intend

```
if($var1 -match "6.1.?" -or "6.2.?" -or "6.3.?")
if(($var1 -match "6.1.?") -or ("6.2.?" -or "6.3.?"))
```

The two lines above function the same. To break down the second operation `("6.2.?" -or "6.3.?")` just a little more: A non-zero length string converted to boolean will always be `$true`. Comparing two non-zero length string with `-or` will always return `$true`. The first clause `($var1 -match "6.1.?")` in your example is `$false`. `If($true -or $false)` is essentially what your `If` statement boils down to which, again, would always return `$true`. Adams answer show how to get the logic you are looking for

```
if($var1 -match "6.1.?" -or $var1 -match "6.2.?" -or $var1 -match "6.3.?") 
if(($var1 -match "6.1.?") -or ($var1 -match "6.2.?") -or ($var1 -match "6.3.?"))
```

Both the above statements are the same. The second one helps understand the logic. For more information see [about_Logical_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847789.aspx). You only need brackets when the logic is not acting the way you want it to.